# google maps autocomplete bounces back already cleared text ...odd....odd...odd

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I have this odd behavior from Google MAPs autocomplete (or maybe I miss sth)... ideas? The odd:

1. You enter sth into the input, e.g. 'London'
2. You press [ENTER]
3. You press [CLEAR] button
4. You click into the 'input'
5. You click outside the 'input'

....... and voila! The already cleared in step-3 text ('London' in our example) is right-back into the input...Why?

And here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>MY FORM</h1>
    <input type='text' id='myInput' size='50' placeholder='Enter text'>
    <input type='button' value='clear' onclick='clearInput()'>

    <script>
                var myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');
                var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(myInput);
                function clearInput(){
                    myInput.value = '';
                }

                myInput.addEventListener('change', function(){
                        console.log(event['target']['value']);

                }, false);

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Answering the "why" complicated, because the source of the API-source is compressed, hard to say what's really going on there.

Of course the value of the input must be stored somewhere, because it must be restored in some cases(e.g. when you switch between the values of the dropdown).

Basically an autocomplete is listening for 4 events in the input:

```
focus, keydown, keyup, blur
```

None of these events will fire in your function, so the autocomplete may not recognize the new value.

Possible solution:trigger these events in your function:

```
function clearInput(){
  google.maps.event.trigger(myInput,'focus');
  myInput.value = '';
  google.maps.event.trigger(myInput,'keydown',{keyCode:46});
  google.maps.event.trigger(myInput,'keyup',{keyCode:46});
  google.maps.event.trigger(myInput,'blur');
}
```

You may send a bug-report, this is not the expected behaviour and should be fixed.

Comment: Status update: bug-report posted to Google Maps APIv3 team (autocomplete issues)... Upon reply I will update. The initial tests show that this solution is a FIX for the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @user3126121 could you please give a link to the bug-report?